# How can I download a printable section of Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, printing

I would like to download parts of Google maps in PDF format so that it can be printed out so I have a backup in case my phone dies or was forgotten. Screenshots will not work because there are widgets onscreen and if I zoom out I loose a lot of information. How can I download a portion of Google maps for printing?

Alternate title:

> How can I convert Google maps to paper maps?

Comment: You need to provide more details.  For example at what magnification are you looking to print and how large an area?  What are the *"widgets onscreen"* that you don't want to include?

Comment: @BlindSpots Perhaps an 11x17 mile rectangle. The widgets are the zoom buttons, the street view man, etc.

Comment: I think you cannot download a PDF including widgets.

Comment: @user67275 How about excluding the widgets?

Comment: Without clearer specs, this isn't possible with Google Maps. The best you could do is montage a larger image by stringing together many smaller ones. Even if you managed to produce the image you want, I doubt you could feasibly print it and retain legibility. The best option is just to buy an actual map for the area you're interested in. For example, in the UK, there's [Collins Pocket Maps](https://collins.co.uk/collections/reference-collins-pocket-maps). They're cheap, and likely less headache than finding a way to fetch and print such a large portion of Google Maps in comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a printable section of Google Maps by following these steps:

1. Open Google Maps on your computer.
2. Search for the location you want to print.
3. Click on the three lines at the top left corner of the screen.
4. Select “Print” from the drop-down menu.
   Enter notes if required. (Optional)
5. Click on “Print” at the top right corner of the screen.
6. Select “Save as PDF” from the "Destination" drop-down menu.
7. Adjust the print options to fit your needs.
   Change "Orientation" to Landscape to fit the map better.
   Click on "More Settings" to see more options.
8. Click "Save".
9. Choose filename and destination location.
10. Click "Save".

Answer (score -2):

try acrobat pro which creates pdf,
I think your file will be vector based, which you can zoom in and out.
but sure you will lose some information still..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can that software interact with Google maps?

Comment: Also just a software rec is a weak answer.